# Datepicker Formulario

Tags: php, drupal

He creado un módulo en Drupal 8 que crea un bloque con su respectivo form , todo funciona bien, pero no consigo ponerle un campo datepicker , he provado varias cosas pero no funcionan.

```
 $form['date'] = [
            '#type' => 'date_range',
            '#title' => $this->t('Date'),
            '#date_date_format' => $date_format,
            '#date_time_format' => $time_format,
            '#description' => date($date_format, time()),
            '#default_value' => DrupalDateTime::createFromTimestamp(time()),
        ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Según la API de formularios de Drupal, se debería poner el `#type` a `datepicker`:

```
$form['date'] = array(
  '#type' => 'datepicker',
  '#date_format' => 'd/m/Y',
);
```

**[Referencia a Drupal](https://www.drupal.org/project/datepicker)**

Comment: Tampoco funciona , el campo no llega al template aparece en blanco.